# How to get scrollLeft() from kendoVirtualScrollable

Tags: jquery, kendo-grid, telerik-grid

I have a kendoGrid with virtual scrolling. Now i am trying to go to a certain position on the grid. I was able to get the top position by using:

```
 //Get the virtualScrollable
var vs = mainGrid.wrapper.find('.k-grid-content').data('kendoVirtualScrollable');
var scrollTop = vs.verticalScrollbar.scrollTop();

//go to the position
$("#mainGrid div.k-virtual-scrollable-wrap").animate({scrollTop: scrollTop}, 0);
$("#mainGrid div.k-scrollbar-vertical").animate({scrollTop: scrollTop}, 0);
```

which works perfectly for getting me to auto scroll down.

now i want to scroll to the right...

**NOPE!**

i cant find scrollLeft()! For some reason kendoVirtualScrollable only has verticalScrollbar and not horizontalScrollbar.

Also, when i use developer tools to try and click on the horizontal scroll bar it keeps pointing to .k-virtual-scrollable-wrap which has a scrollLeft() = 0.

Anyone out there know how to get the scrollLeft() of kendoVirtualScrollable??

Comment: Just curious, what's the purpose of doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works for me:

https://dojo.telerik.com/abEYO/4

```
    $('.k-virtual-scrollable-wrap').animate({
        scrollLeft: 300
    }, 1000);

setTimeout(function () {
      alert($('.k-virtual-scrollable-wrap').scrollLeft());
      }, 5000);
```

Comment: yeah i can scroll left. But I'm trying to get the current position of the horizontal scrollbar. so i can do something like var horizontalbar = horizontalbar.scrollLeft();  $('.k-virtual-scrollable-wrap').animate({
        scrollLeft: horizontalbar 
    }, 1000);

Comment: unfortunately $('.k-virtual-scrollable-wrap').scrollLeft() is always going to be zero, because that's the scroll left of the entire wrap and not the horizontal scrollbar. I'm just trying to get the horizontal scrollbars position, then animating it that position again.

Comment: hmm in my example it works (300 in the alert), i just updated the above code

Comment: you have to set a timeout on it else it will just be 0 on page load. You have to wait for it to scroll, then get the position. Did you do this?

Comment: Ok i see it now. Now i have to wonder why i keep seeing 0 in my application.

Comment: for your application, how are you using it? does the grid load and it scrolls to position, and then you click on something to get the position of the scrollbar?

Comment: Ok so it looks like by time it got to my databound horizontal position was already at 0. So i had to save its position in dataBinding as a global then set it in dataBound. but it works now.