# How to go to last position in Kendo UI with Virtual Scrolling in IE11

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui

After binding the grid it cannot stay put and sends you to the top of the grid losing your place. I managed to write some script to save the users position on the grid, then after binding it scrolls the user back to that saved location:
[How to get scrollLeft() from kendoVirtualScrollable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46937801/how-to-get-scrollleft-from-kendovirtualscrollable/46938319?noredirect=1#comment80825524_46938319)

This seems to only work if the user is either at the top of the grid or the bottom of the grid. If the user is in the middle of the grid (during virtual scrolling) it is unable to save the scrollTop().

I put this Dojo together to simplify the issue I am experiencing.

http://dojo.telerik.com/upIto

1. Press "TEST POSITION" which will bring you to scrollTop: 3360. (Note: The position on the grid. For me the top OrderID was 10328).
2. Press "TEST POSITION" again(scrollTop has not changed).
3. The scroll now brings the user to a different location. (my new top OrderID being 10365).
4. The user has lost their place. Also note how the scroll bar stays in place.

This is undesirable to the user.

Any help with this bug is greatly appreciated.

**UPDATE**

if i set the scrollTop to 0 before going to new location it seems to bring me generally a row above the position.

I added this:

```
   $("#grid div.k-scrollbar-vertical").scrollTop(0);
   $("#grid div.k-virtual-scrollable-wrap").animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, 0);
    $("#grid div.k-scrollbar-vertical").animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, 0);
```

before

```
   $("#grid div.k-virtual-scrollable-wrap").animate({ scrollTop: 3360 }, 0);
    $("#grid div.k-scrollbar-vertical").animate({ scrollTop: 3360 }, 0);
```

Pressed the 'TEST POSITION' once: OrderID: 10329. Pressed it again: OrderID 10328.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK so this is a bug and apparently it has been fixed in the 2017 release.

"From our 2017 R3 release, we officially support the editing with virtual scrolling.

Please check our new demo and advise if there are any scrolling issue after the new implementation:

http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/grid/virtualization-local-data"

-Stefan (Telerik Admin)